# MacOSX YosemiteでAutomatorで自作したサービスをショートカットキーに割り当てる方法

Tags: macos, automator

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上記のようなサービスをAutomatorで自作し、下図のように適当なショートカットキーを割り当てたのですがショートカットキーを押してもコンコン鳴るだけでAppleScriptが実行されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Automatorから実行ボタンをクリックする際には実行され、ちゃんと「Hello World」のダイアログが表示されます。

セキュリティとプライバシーのアクセシビリティの設定に誤りがあるのかと思ったのですが、`Automator.app`や`スクリプトエディタ.app`はコンピュータの制御を許可してあります。自作したサービス自体にアクセシビリティの許可が必要なのかと思い、HelloWorld.workflowを追加しようとしたのですが、実行形式のアプリケーションしか対応していないようで追加できませんでした。

なにがいけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

画像の通り選択項目が「オーディオファイル」になっているのであれば、
m4a等のファイルを選択した状態でショットカットキーを押せば実行できると思います。

何も選択していない状態で使用したいのであれば「入力なし」にすると良いかもしれません。
※workflowを編集した後はショットカットキーを再設定した方が良さそうです。

Comment: 入力なしに設定したら無事動作するようになりました。ありがとうございますm(_ _)m